# Regarding direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a direct sum of cyclic groups that is isomorphic to the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^{3}/N$, where $N$ is the subgroup generated by
$\left\lbrace (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 0, 2) \right\rbrace$.

I know the answer is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ but I dont know why. Would someone be able to explain?

Comment: $N$ is also generated by $(2,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ be given by $\phi((l,m,n))=(l,m,n)\mod 2$.

I will let you check that $\phi$ is a homomorphism and the kernel of this homomorphism is precisely $N$. Now applying the first isomorphism theorem, we have that
$$\mathbb{Z}^3/N\cong image(\phi).$$

But $\phi$ is clearly surjective.